# Matching Company names in Python through Cosine Similarity, TF-IDF and pyspark

Tags: python, string-matching, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to match company names from 2 lists together, in order to check if a company in list A is indeed listed in list B. As company names a written in all kinds of different forms, I leaned toward a match using the cosing similarity. 
For this, I followed the note on this blog made by Ran Tavory : [Link Here](https://medium.com/@rantav/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e)

Here is the general outline:

> 1. Calculate TF-IDF matrices on the driver.
> 2. Parallelize matrix A; Broadcast matrix B
> 3. Each worker now flatMaps its chunk of work by multiplying its chunk of matrix A with the entire matrix B. So if a worker operates on
>      A[0:99] then it would multiply these hundred rows and return the
>      result of, say A[13] matches a name found in B[21]. Multiplication is
>      done using numpy.
> 4. The driver would collect back all the results from the different workers and match the indices (A[13] and B[21]) to the actual names in
>      the original dataset — and we’re done!

I was able to run the exact code described in the note, but one part of it seems kind of odd : 
`b_mat_dist = broadcast_matrix(a_mat)`

When broadcasting a_mat as well as parallelize a_mat, I get a logical result of a perfect match for every company names (as we're looking in the same source).

When I try broadcasting the b_mat : b_mat_dist = broadcast_matrix(b_mat), I get the following error : *`Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 56710 while Y.shape[1] == 2418`*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance !

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

if 'sc' in locals():
    sc.stop()

sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
RefB =  pd.read_excel('Ref.xlsx')
ToMatchB =  pd.read_excel('ToMatch.xlsx')

Ref = RefB['CLT_company_name']
ToMatch = ToMatchB ['Name1']

a_mat = vectorizer.fit_transform(Ref)
b_mat = vectorizer.fit_transform(ToMatch)

def find_matches_in_submatrix(sources, targets, inputs_start_index,
                              threshold=.8):
    cosimilarities = cosine_similarity(sources, targets)
    for i, cosimilarity in enumerate(cosimilarities):
        cosimilarity = cosimilarity.flatten()
        # Find the best match by using argsort()[-1]
        target_index = cosimilarity.argsort()[-1]
        source_index = inputs_start_index + i
        similarity = cosimilarity[target_index]
        if cosimilarity[target_index] >= threshold:
            yield (source_index, target_index, similarity)

def broadcast_matrix(mat):
    bcast = sc.broadcast((mat.data, mat.indices, mat.indptr))
    (data, indices, indptr) = bcast.value
    bcast_mat = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=mat.shape)
    return bcast_mat

def parallelize_matrix(scipy_mat, rows_per_chunk=100):
    [rows, cols] = scipy_mat.shape
    i = 0
    submatrices = []
    while i < rows:
        current_chunk_size = min(rows_per_chunk, rows - i)
        submat = scipy_mat[i:i + current_chunk_size]
        submatrices.append((i, (submat.data, submat.indices, 
                                submat.indptr),
                            (current_chunk_size, cols)))
        i += current_chunk_size
    return sc.parallelize(submatrices)

a_mat_para = parallelize_matrix(a_mat, rows_per_chunk=100)
b_mat_dist = broadcast_matrix(b_mat)
results = a_mat_para.flatMap(
        lambda submatrix:
        find_matches_in_submatrix(csr_matrix(submatrix[1],
                                             shape=submatrix[2]),
                                   b_mat_dist,
                                   submatrix[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try equalising vocabulary for both TfidVectorizer object:

```
vect = CountVectorizer()
vocabulary =  vect.fit(Ref + ToMatch).vocabulary_
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
```

Also based on what you are aiming to do:

```
a_mat = vectorizer.fit_transform(ToMatch)
b_mat = vectorizer.fit_transform(Ref)
```

looked like a better option to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I implemented your comments but I still get the error `Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 56710 while Y.shape[1] == 2418`

Comment: Just to confirm, have you replaced "Ref" with "ToMatch"?